# LDAP role/group membership

Tags: regex, authentication, ldap, user-groups

We have many users registered in our LDAP auth. So far we've only stored login and mail-related information in this LDAP.

In our main application (Play! Framework), we needed to modelise roles (understand:  privileges) for our members, and it was decided to recreate a database, pull login/mail info from ldap, and only assign a role from within this application, and not from an ldap field.

However, we realise now that these roles could be used by another application (We are thinking on restricting Dokuwiki access to our users). And So I thought it would be better to store this "role" in LDAP rather than our application database. How ? That's my question.

**In practice**, in our main application, users are given a "role" field, from which we do regex matches to determine affiliated groups

Example : a user with role: "responsible for quality department and member of comm department" should be matched to groups "quality" and "communication"

So how should I "translate" that to LDAP so that this user would be able to access the "quality" and "communication" reserved sections of Dokuwiki (via Auth plugin). (I don't have a lot of experience with LDAP)

*Or maybe there's an easier way to use the existing database from our Play! project to easily define Dokuwiki groups ?*